# Import mySql file to Amazon rds

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have sql file (mySQL) and i want to import this data to amazon rds database. Iv'e opened mySQL database in amazon and i don't find any way to import the data. Iv'e looked for some tutorials and docs but nothing found so far.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `mysqldump` to create database backup.

```
sudo mysqldump -u localuser \
  --databases world \
  --single-transaction \
  --compress \
  --order-by-primary  \
  -plocalpassword | mysql -u rdsuser \
      --port=3306 \
      --host=myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com \
      -prdspassword
```

[Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.SmallExisting.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the procedure to Set up db instance with amazone. did you followed this link ?

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/migrate-database-rds/

if yes , then share your error details